# create zip folder with password in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to create zip folder with password which will ask for password while extracting zip folder using java script at client side.There is one example http://viralpatel.net/blogs/create-zip-file-javascript/ of zip folder creation without password but how can i make it password protected.Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: jszip used in given example link doesn't support [password protected zip](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/documentation/api_jszip/load.html). Check different library

Comment: is there any js to make it password proetcted?

Comment: If you're encrypting it on the client-side then the client is going to have access to the password. Is this intentional?

Comment: client will have password !!